# Placemarker and non-placemarker tokens in pre-processor?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, c99

C99 standard and having trouble to understand this :

```
c99 - 6.10.3.3  
Semantics 
3
```

---  (2nd sentence)

`Placemarker preprocessing tokens` are handled specially: concatenation of two placemarkers results in a single placemarker preprocessing token, and concatenation of a placemarker 
with a `non-placemarker preprocessing token` results in the non-placemarker preprocessing token.

If the result is not a valid preprocessing token, the behavior is undefined.

```
1.What does this `placemarker` and `non-placemarker` term mean exactly?
2.Why the last line says : `undefined behaviour` ?
```

I have read more than 10 times but still puzzled about these technical names.

Any help with examples and little explanations will help me more.

Answer (score 4):

Placemarker tokens are defined in the preceding paragraph (6.10.3.2):

> If, in the replacement list of a function-like macro, a parameter is immediately preceded
>   or followed by a `##` preprocessing token, the parameter is replaced by the corresponding
>   argument’s preprocessing token sequence; however, if an argument consists of no
>   preprocessing tokens, the parameter is replaced by a *placemarker* preprocessing token
>   instead.<sup>145)</sup>

And the footnote:

> 145) Placemarker preprocessing tokens do not appear in the syntax because they are temporary entities that
>   exist only within translation phase 4.

And the last line you quoted doesn't say "undefined behaviour", it says "the behavior is undefined". I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for here. It says so because the authors of the standard decided so.

Comment: Yeah that's fine which you have quoted , but my question is clear , what is placemaker and non-placemaker tokens. It's just written like :`"however, if an argument consists of no preprocessing tokens, the parameter is replaced by a placemarker preprocessing token instead"` but it says nothing about placemaker.

Comment: also `"behaviour is undefined"` and `"undefined behaviours "` are they different ?

Comment: First off, it's "placemarker", not "placemaker". Second, that's all it is: a special token that marks where an argument consisting of no tokens was expanded.